# How do I access LoginPath within a controller or a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have something like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    ...
});
```

How can I access whatever I set as LoginPath elsewhere in my code (controllers, views, etc.) ? For example I would like to pass my login URL to my SPA in a controller method (returns JSON). Or, in a Razor view, I would like to create a login button.

Of course I could just duplicate the string, but I was wondering if there was some way to access the CookieAuthenticationOptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this value, example:

```
    public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> cookieAuthenticationOptions)
    {
        _cookieAuthenticationOptions = cookieAuthenticationOptions.Get(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var loginPath = _cookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath;
    }
```